# How to create a set with my customized comparison in c++

Tags: c++, set, c-strings

Could someone explain me what is going on in this example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/)?

They declare the following:

```
bool fncomp (int lhs, int rhs) {return lhs<rhs;}
```

And then use as:

```
bool(*fn_pt)(int,int) = fncomp;
std::set<int,bool(*)(int,int)> sixth (fn_pt)
```

While the example for the sort method in algorithm library [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

can do like this:

```
bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }
std::sort (myvector.begin()+4, myvector.end(), myfunction);
```

I also didn't understand the following:

```
struct classcomp {
    bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const
       {return lhs<rhs;}
};
```

this keyword operator (not being followed by an operator as in a op. overload)... what is the meaning of it? Any operator applied there will have that behavior? And this const modifier... what is the effect caused by it?

I was trying to make a set of C-style string as follows:

```
typedef struct 
{
   char grid[7];
} wrap;

bool compare(wrap w1, wrap w2)
{
   return strcmp(w1.grid, w2.grid) == -1;
}
set <wrap, compare> myset;
```

I thought I could create a set defining my sorting function in a similar as when I call sort from algorithm library... once it didn't compile I went to the documentation and saw this syntax that got me confused... Do I need to declare a pointer to a function as in the first example i pasted here?

Comment: *not being followed by an operator* - It sure is being followed by an operator. This is all covered in introductory C++ [books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), though.

Comment: have you even clicked the link and seen that there IT IS NOT? @chris

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is not that is covered in the link? The link says nothing about books and `operator()` is most certainly an operator. Unless you were referring to my link, in which case, I'm not sure how to respond.

Comment: I'm used to see overloading like this: " Myclass operator+(const Myclass& other); "   Since it was for a comparison I was expecting to see: " bool operator< ( ... ", I'll read something about functors later and try to understand what is going there... I never read C++ books, I have some background in C and I'm trying to learn some C++ data structures so I basically search stuff when I need to use them (sets in this case)

Comment: Note: `strcmp() < 0` is the proper "less-than" test... it may or may not be -1.  (Some implementations subtract the ASCII characters and return when that's non-0, i.e. `strcmp("A", "B")` returns -1, but strcmp("A", "C") returns -2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct classcomp {
    bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const
       {return lhs<rhs;}
};
```

Defines a functor by overloading the *function call operator*. To use a function you can do:

```
int main() {
    std::set <wrap, bool (*)(wrap,wrap)> myset(compare);
    return 0;
```

}

Another alternative is to define the operator as a part of the `wrap` class:

```
struct wrap {
    char grid[7];
    bool operator<(const wrap& rhs) const {
        return strcmp(this->grid, rhs.grid) == -1; 
    }
};

int main() {
    wrap a;
    std::set <wrap> myset;
    myset.insert(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what?? Overloading? so if I call the operator + it will call that function too?

Comment: sure, it will be called when you add relevant types.

Comment: so If I say wrap1 + wrap2 it would evaluate the expression as if I wanted to know if (wrap1 < wrap2) and return me a boolean value?

Comment: if you define `+` like that yes. Normally functors only define the call operator `()`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, thats mostly what I wanted to know.. I will read a little bit about functors(first time i heard this name was in your answer) later, first time you typed it I thought it was a typo haha

Comment: What is the meaning of this const modifier before the function body? Is it forbidden some subclass of changing that (something like c# sealed or java final)?

Comment: it means that the comparison does not change the state of the object at the left hand side of the operator. So that you can compare `const` objects too.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there... here's a "fixed" version of your code ([see it run here at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/FftZ8d)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

typedef struct 
{
   char grid[7];
} wrap;

bool compare(wrap w1, wrap w2) // more efficient: ...(const wrap& e1, const wrap@ w2)
{
   return strcmp(w1.grid, w2.grid) < 0;
}

set <wrap, bool(*)(wrap, wrap)> myset(compare);

int main() {
    wrap w1 { "abcdef" };
    wrap w2 { "ABCDEF" };
    myset.insert(w1);
    myset.insert(w2);
    std::cout << myset.begin()->grid[0] << '\n';
}
```

> "explain [to] me what is going on in this example"

Well, the crucial line is...

```
std::set<wrap, bool(*)(wrap, wrap)> myset(compare);
```

...which uses the second template parameter to specify the type of function that will perform comparisons, then uses the constructor argument to specify the function.  The `set` object will store a pointer to the function, and invoke it when it needs to compare elements.

> "the example for the sort method in algorithm library..."

`std::sort` in `algorithm` is great for e.g. `vector`s, which aren't automatically sorted as elements are inserted but can be sorted at any time.  `std::set` though needs to maintain sorted order constantly, as the logic for inserting new elements, finding and erasing existing ones etc. all assumes the existing elements are always sorted.  Consequently, you can't apply `std::sort()` to an existing `std::set`.

> "this keyword `operator` (not being followed by an operator as in a op. overload)... what is the meaning of it? Any operator applied there will have that behavior? And this const modifier... what is the effect caused by it?

`operator()(...)` can be invoked on the object using the same notation used to call a function, e.g.:

```
classcomp my_classcomp;
if (my_classcomp(my_int1, my_int_2))
    std::cout << "<\n";
```

As you can see, `my_classcomp` is "called" as if it were a function.  The `const` modifier means that the code above works even if `my_classcomp` is defined as a `const classcomp`, because the comparison function does not need to modify any member variables of the `classcomp` object (if there were any data members).

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered your question:

```
bool compare(wrap w1, wrap w2)
{
   return strcmp(w1.grid, w2.grid) == -1;
}

struct wrap_comparer
{
    bool operator()(const wrap& _Left, const wrap& _Right) const
    {
        return strcmp(_Left.grid, _Right.grid) == -1;
    }
};

// declares pointer to function
bool(*fn_pt)(wrap,wrap) = compare;
// uses constructor with function pointer argument
std::set<wrap,bool(*)(wrap,wrap)> new_set(fn_pt);
// uses the function directly
std::set<wrap,bool(*)(wrap,wrap)> new_set2(compare);
// uses comparer
std::set<wrap, wrap_comparer> new_set3;
```

std::sort can use either a function pointer or a function object (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/), as well as std::set constructor.

const modifier after function signature means that function can't modify object state and so can be called on a const object.

Comment: Hum... I saw that the second parameter could be a boolean function(or at least thats what it seemed to be to me) and thought the syntax would be the same as a call to sort()